# SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host. Error when trying to connect to remote MariaDB with Java

Tags: java, sockets, exception, jdbc, mariadb

I'm facing an issue while connecting to a remote MariaDB database from my work using Java. I have to use an SSH connection.

For the SSH part, I'm using the dependency Jsch

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mwiede</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

and I'm using for the connection with MariaDB the dependency:

```
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
         <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.4</version>
     </dependency>
```

I can connect with the server using SSH with Jsch with the following code:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
jsch.setKnownHosts(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/.ssh/known_hosts");
jsch.addIdentity(publicKey);
session = jsch.getSession(sshUserName, sshServer, remoteSSHPort);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "yes");
session.connect();
```

But when I'm trying to connect with the Database using this code,

```
public Connection connectToDB() throws Exception {

    int assignedPort = session.setPortForwardingL(localPort,serverHost,remoteSSHPort);
    String url = "jdbc:mariadb://" + serverHost + ":" + assignedPort + "/" + database;

    return DriverManager.getConnection(url,userSQL,passwordSql);
}
```

It fails in the `DriverManager.getConnection()` part with the error: `SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=database)(port=3306)(type=primary). database`.

For some reason, when I use DBeaver to connect to this Database I don't have any issue, it connects smoothly.

Trying to solve this issue, I have tried different types of solutions.

For example:

Using the different ways of sending the information in DriverManager.getConnection() method:

- `getConnection(String url, String user, String password)`
- `getConnection(String url)`
- `getConnection(String url, java.util.Properties info)`

Finally, I have tried without results using the code:

```
while(session.isConnected()){
    Connection connection = connectToDB();
    System.out.println("connected to DB...");
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
}
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Try to change the hostname or port.